Is it possible to change Weston toolbar size?
I know that in weston.ini
when I set
panel-position=none

I can hide my toolbar on weston
but now instead of hiding I want to show the toolbar but with smaller width x height
changing resolution is not the way I want cause my device only support 480x272
is it possible to do so? or any close approach
